# Receive and send data from arduino to c# and vice versa

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-communication

first of all I started using c# yesterday morning so I apologize for potential numb questions.

So far I wrote the following code. I'm able to send data from c# to arduino which seems to be working fine. Now i would like to receive data from arduino, through serial.print, at the same time and display it in a box (ListBox?). How could add this to the code?

I would be thankful for any input, tips and ideas.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stop.Enabled = false;
            left.Enabled = false;
            right.Enabled = false;
            up.Enabled = false;
            down.Enabled = false;
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                string port = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                serialPort2.PortName = port; // "port";
                serialPort2.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort2.Open();
                if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
                {
                    start.Enabled = false;
                    stop.Enabled = true;
                    left.Enabled = true;
                    right.Enabled = true;
                    up.Enabled = true;
                    down.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please connect the Arduino and select a Port");
                }

        }
        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort2.Close();
                start.Enabled = true;
                stop.Enabled = false;
                left.Enabled = false;
                right.Enabled = false;
                up.Enabled = false;
                down.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        private void up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort2.WriteLine("1");
            }

        }

        private void left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort2.WriteLine("4");
            }

        }

        private void right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort2.WriteLine("2");
            }
        }

        private void down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort2.WriteLine("3");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? Do you want to receive a response for each button click or do you want to continuously receive and display data regardless of the activity?

Comment: Yes, continuously receiving and displaying data regardless of me sending data to the arduino

Comment: You'll want to use a separate thread to handle receiving the data from the Arduino. There are many examples of using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle work while the application UI thread continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [SolidSoils4Arduino](https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino) you can simultaneously read and write serial messages. The `Solid.Arduino.IStringProtocol` supports asynchronous reading of string messages and the `Solid.Arduino.ArduinoSession` has a `StringReceived` event that fires when a message has been received.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a lightweight solution, you can have a look on Sharer : https://github.com/Rufus31415/Sharer

```cpp
#include <Sharer.h>

// A simple function that sums an integer and a byte and return an integer
int Sum(int a, byte b) {
    return a + b;
}

// A simple function that return a^2
float Square(float a) {
    return a * a;
}

// Init Sharer and declare your function to share
void setup() {
    Sharer.init(115200); // Init Serial communication with 115200 bauds

    // Expose this function to Sharer : int Sum(int a, byte b) 
    Sharer_ShareFunction(int, Sum, int, a, byte, b);

    // Expose this function to Sharer : float Square(float a)
    Sharer_ShareFunction(float, Square, float, a);
}

// Run Sharer engine in the main Loop
void loop() {
    Sharer.run();
}
```

In your C# application :

```cs
// Connect to Arduino board
var connection = new SharerConnection("COM3", 115200);
connection.Connect();

// Scan all functions shared
connection.RefreshFunctions();

// remote call function on Arduino and wait for the result
var result = connection.Call("Sum", 10, 12);

// Display the result
Console.WriteLine("Status : " + result.Status);
Console.WriteLine("Type : " + result.Type);
Console.WriteLine("Value : " + result.Value);

// Status : OK
// Type : int
// Value : 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same like you, but I have used a Potentiometer.
The Pot analogic output is sent to C# over Serial; and C# application reads it.
The only difference is that I have used the protocols to read from Arduino.
Your Arduino Sketch Code depends on what you are trying to send and/or receive.
I'm providing my example. I hope this helps.

**C# Code**

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;

namespace ArduinoValor
{
   internal class Class1
   {
    public string port = "";

    static SerialPort currentPort;

    public Boolean connect(int baud, string recognizeText, byte paramone, byte paramtwo, byte paramthree)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
            buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(paramone);
            buffer[1] = Convert.ToByte(paramtwo); // For Details
            buffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(paramthree);

            int intReturnASCII = 0;
            char charReturnValue = (Char)intReturnASCII;
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            foreach (string newport in ports)
            {
                currentPort = new SerialPort(newport, baud); 
                currentPort.Open(); // Open Serial Port (Use the Port) 
                currentPort.Write(buffer, 0,3); 
                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                int count = currentPort.BytesToRead; //Read bytes
                string returnMessage = "";

                while (count > 0)
                {
                    intReturnASCII = currentPort.ReadByte();
                    returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
                    count--;
                }

                currentPort.Close();
                port = newport;

                if (returnMessage.Contains(recognizeText))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        catch (Exception e) { return false; }
    }

    public string message(byte paramone, byte paramtwo, byte paramthree)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
            buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(paramone);
            buffer[1] = Convert.ToByte(paramtwo);
            buffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(paramthree);

            currentPort.Open();
            currentPort.Write(buffer, 0, 3);

            int intReturnASCII = 0;
            char charReturnValue = (char)intReturnASCII;

            Thread.Sleep(1000); 

            int count = currentPort.BytesToRead;
            string returnMessage = "";

            while (count > 0)
            {
                intReturnASCII = currentPort.ReadByte();
                returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
                count--;
            }

            currentPort.Close();
            return returnMessage;
        }

        catch (Exception e) { return "Error"; }
    }
}
```

}